# How to upload array of images in each array value of the request?

Tags: android, image, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to send array of images in each value of the request array. How can I send it through retrofit? I know we can send multiple number of images through multipart file. But how can I send many multiple part files? Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: Use REQUEST BODY An object can be specified for use as an HTTP request body with the @Body annotation.


@POST("users/new")
Call<User> createPhotos(@Body PhotoList photos);

Comment: @Bäda.MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
    builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
    builder.addFormDataPart("files",file1.getName(),RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file1));
    builder.addFormDataPart("files",file2.getName(),RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file2)); Did you mean this?